# c++ - find_if condition?

Tags: c++

How do you check if `find_if` has found a match or not? when i try the code below:

```
SparseMatrix& SparseMatrix::operator+=(const SparseMatrix &other)
{
    vector<Node>::iterator itThis;
    for (vector<Node>::const_iterator itOther = other._matrix.begin(); itOther != other._matrix.end(); ++itOther)
    {
        itThis = find_if(_matrix.begin(), _matrix.end(), position_finder(*itOther));

        if(*itThis)
        {
            itThis->value += itOther->value;
        } else
        {
            _matrix.push_back(*itOther);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

I get at `if(*itThis)`:

```
could not convert ‘itThis.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Node*, _Container = std::vector<Node>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Node&]()’ from ‘Node’ to ‘bool’
```

I understand that `itThis` is a constant so i cant change it's value but i want to know whether there was a match at all.

Comment: This would be one of those [RTFM](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find_if returns iterator to either element in container or to `end()`, see [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

You could compare `itThis`  with `_matrix.end()`

```
if( itThis != _matrix.end())
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if:

> `find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p )`
>
> ...
>
> **Return value**
>
> Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or `last` if no such element is found.

Answer (score 2):

If an item is not found `find_if` returns an iterator equal to `_matrix.end()`.

```
if (itThis == _matrix.end()) { ... }
```